# Selecting paragraph by name and not by location with Python Docx

Tags: python, docx

I am using docx to edit paragraphs, you understand I can use:

```
document.paragraphs[15] = "Hello world"
```

Is there a way to select the paragraph using its name? Something like:

```
document.paragraphs[docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph object at 0x112dbbe48] = "Hello world"
```

Answer (score 2):

Say, you want to set the paragraph referenced by the variable `p`.
One obvious solution would be simply getting its index:

```
document.paragraphs[document.paragraphs.index(p)] = "Hello world"
```